# QueryDSL subtract Dates

Tags: java, mysql, date, querydsl

I want to update the field `state` to 1 in elements of the table intervals where state is 0 and a related latency is less than the subtract of a parametrized timestamp of the table Mm and a related timestamp of the table EventPackage. This would be the query:

```
select * from intervals i
join eventpackage e on i.end = e.eventpackage_id
join mm m on i.state = 0 and i.mm_id = m.mm_id
where i.state = 0
and m.latency < (<timestamp_parametrized> - e.timestamp);
```

I am trying to do it using QueryDSL but something is wrong with the Date sub.

```
QInterval interval = QInterval.interval;
QEventPackage eventpackage = QEventPackage.eventPackage;
QMaintenanceMessage mm = QMaintenanceMessage.maintenanceMessage;
JPAQuery<?> query = new JPAQuery<Void>(em);

BooleanExpression ideq0 = interval.state.eq(0);     

// Actual timestamp less interval.end timestamp
SimpleOperation<Long> a = Expressions.operation(Long.class, Ops.SUB, 
                Expressions.constant(<timestamp_parametrized>), eventpackage.timestamp);    

new JPAUpdateClause(em, interval).where(interval.in((List<Interval>) query.from(interval)
                    .innerJoin(interval.end,eventpackage)
                    .innerJoin(interval.mm,mm)
                    .where(ideq0.and(mm.latency.lt(a)))
                    .fetchResults().getResults())).set(interval.state,Expressions.constant(1)).execute();
```

How can I make a Date sub with a Java parameter and Date to obtain a long in milliseconds properly? Thanks.